# null conditional operator not working with nullable types?

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator, c#-6.0

I'm writing a piece of code in c#6 and for some strange reason this works

```
var value = objectThatMayBeNull?.property;
```

but this doesn't:

```
int value = nullableInt?.Value;
```

By not works I mean I get a compile error saying `Cannot resolve symbol 'Value'`.
Any idea why the null conditional operator `?.` isn't working?

Comment: did you tried: int value = (nullableInt?).Value; ???

Comment: You should use the `??` operator in this situation. As in `nullableInt ?? 0`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Okay, I have done some thinking and testing. This is what happens:

```
int value = nullableInt?.Value;
```

Gives this error message when compiling:

> Type 'int' does not contain a definition for `Value'

That means that `?` 'converts' the `int?` into the actual `int` value. This is effectively the same as:

```
int value = nullableInt ?? default(int);
```

The result is an integer, which doesn't have a `Value`, obviously.

Okay, might this help?

```
int value = nullableInt?;
```

No, that syntax isn't allowed.

So what then? Just keep using `.GetValueOrDefault()` for this case.

```
int value = nullableInt.GetValueOrDefault();
```

Comment: Well I would have thought this would have been one of the main use-cases for this operator, especially since it's just sintactic sugar.

Answer (score 21):

The reason for this is that accessing the value with a null conditional operator would be pointless:

- When you apply `x?.p` where `p` is a non-nullable value type `T`, the result is of type `T?`. By the same token, the result of `nullableInt?.Value` operation *must* be nullable.
- When your `Nullable<T>` has a value, the result of `nullableInt?.Value` would be the same as the value itself
- When your `Nullable<T>` does not have a value, the result would be `null`, which is, again, the same as the value itself.

Although it does not make sense to access `Value` with the `?.` operator, it does make sense to access other properties of nullable value types. The operator works consistently with nullable value types and with reference types, so these two implementations produce identical behavior:

```
class PointClass {
    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; }
    public PointClass(int x, int y) { X = x; Y = y; }
}
struct PointStruct {
    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; }
    public PointStruct(int x, int y) { X = x; Y = y; }
}
...
PointClass pc = ...
PointStruct? ps = ...
int? x = pc?.X;
int? y = ps?.Y;
```

In case of a nullable `struct` the operator lets you access a property of the underlying type `PointStruct`, and it adds nullability to the result in the same way that it does for non-nullable properties of the reference type `PointClass`.

Comment: That's not the case here. It's because, just as with the null-coalescing operator, `?.` resolves to the wrapped `int`, not the nullable type itself.

Comment: Now that you pointed this out I realize how moronic my logic was. Not a good day for science.

Comment: They don't compile because the result of `?.` when the nullable is non-null is the actual `int` inside it which doesn't have `Value` or `HasValue` properties. As in my answer, try `nullableInt?.ToString()`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight `DateTime? dt=DateTime.Now; int? day=dt?.Day;`. After `?.` should come property of `DateTime` not property of `DateTime?`.

Comment: "because ?. may return null" > wrong, it returns an `int`. So the end result of `someInt?.XXX` would be the same as `someInt.GetValueOrDefault().XXX`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: No, it would be: `someInt.HasValue ? someInt.GetValueOrDefault().XXX : null`

Answer (score 11):

With regards to nullable types, the `?.` operator is saying `if not null, use the wrapped value`. So for a nullable int, if the nullable has value `8`, the result of `?.` would be `8`, not the nullable that contains `8`. Since `Value` is not a property of an `int`, you get an error.

So, the example of trying to use property `Value` quite rightly fails, but the following would work,

`var x = nullableInt?.ToString();`

Consider the null-coalescing operator, `??`.

`var x = nullableInt ?? 0;`

Here, the operator says, `if null, return 0, otherwise return the value inside the nullable`, which in this case is an `int`. The `?.` operator is performing similarly with regards to extracting the content of the nullable.

For your specific example, you should use the `??` operator and an appropriate default rather than the `?.` operator.

Comment: `var x = nullableInt ?? 0` won't compile because `nullableInt` and `0` are different types: `Nullable<int>` and `int`, respectively. You must use `nullableInt.GetValueOrDefault(0)`; or, `nullableInt.GetValueOrDefault()`, since `default(int)` is `0`.

Comment: @Suncat2000 that's verifiably not true.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/NDPJ44

Answer (score 7):

I basically agree with the other answers.  I was just hoping that the observed behavior could be backed up by some form of authoritative documentation.

Since I can't find the C# 6.0 specification anywhere (is it out yet?), the closest I found to "documentation" are the [C# Language Design Notes for Feb 3, 2014](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/540281). Assuming the information found in there still reflects the current state of affairs, here are the relevant parts that formally explain the observed behavior.

> The semantics are like applying the ternary operator to a null equality check, a null literal and a non-question-marked application of the operator, except that the expression is evaluated only once:
>
> ```
> e?.m(…)   =>   ((e == null) ? null : e0.m(…))
> e?.x      =>   ((e == null) ? null : e0.x)
> e?.$x     =>   ((e == null) ? null : e0.$x)
> e?[…]     =>   ((e == null) ? null : e0[…])
> ```
>
> Where `e0` is the same as `e`, ***except if `e` is of a nullable value type, in which case `e0` is `e.Value`.***

Applying that last rule to:

```
nullableInt?.Value
```

... the semantically equivalent expression becomes:

```
((nullableInt == null) ? null : nullableInt.Value.Value)
```

Clearly, `nullableInt.Value.Value` can't compile, and that's what you observed.

As to why the design decision was made to apply that special rule to nullable types specifically, I think `dasblinkenlight`'s answer covers that nicely, so I won't repeat it here.

---

Additionally, I should mention that, even if, hypothetically, we didn't have this special rule for nullable types, and the expression `nullableInt?.Value` did compile and behave as you originally thought...

```
// let's pretend that it actually gets converted to this...
((nullableInt == null) ? null : nullableInt.Value)
```

still, the following statement from your question would be invalid and produce a compilation error:

```
int value = nullableInt?.Value; // still would not compile
```

The reason why it would still not work is because the type of the `nullableInt?.Value` expression would be `int?`, not `int`.  So you would need to change the type of the `value` variable to `int?`.

This is also formally covered in the [C# Language Design Notes for Feb 3, 2014](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/540281):

> The type of the result depends on the type `T` of the right hand side of the underlying operator:
>
> - If `T` is (known to be) a reference type, the type of the expression is `T`
> - ***If `T` is (known to be) a non-nullable value type, the type of the expression is `T?`***
> - If `T` is (known to be) a nullable value type, the type of the expression is `T`
> - Otherwise (i.e. if it is not known whether `T` is a reference or value type) the expression is a compile time error.

But if you would then be forced to write the following to make it compile:

```
int? value = nullableInt?.Value;
```

... then it seems pretty pointless, and it wouldn't be any different from simply doing:

```
int? value = nullableInt;
```

As others have pointed out, in your case, you probably meant to use the [null-coalescing operator `??`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) all along, not the [null-conditional operator `?.`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx).

Comment: Ah!  Gotcha!  I actually found this thread, because, when I got an Obj Ref err doing "long? nullableLongVariable = objectVariable.NullableLongProperty.Value;", I had a brain fart, and changed it to "long? nullableLongVariable = objectVariable.NullableLongProperty?.Value;", when I could've just made it "long? nullableLongVariable = objectVariable.NullableLongProperty;".

Answer (score 1):

Simply because (based on sstan's answer above)

```
var value = objectThatMayBeNull?.property;
```

is evaluated by compiler like

```
var value = (objectThatMayBeNull == null) ? null : objectThatMayBeNull.property
```

and

```
int value = nullableInt?.Value;
```

like

```
int value = (nullableInt == null) ? null : nullableInt.Value.Value;
```

when `nullableInt.Value.Value` is `Cannot resolve symbol 'Value'` syntax error!

Answer (score 0):

`int` doesn't have a `Value` property.

Consider:

```
var value = obj?.Property
```

Is equivalent to:

```
value = obj == null ? null : obj.Property;
```

That makes no sense with `int` and hence not with `int?` via `?.`

The old `GetValueOrDefault()` does though make sense with `int?`.

Or for that matter, since `?` has to return something nullable, simply:

```
int? value = nullableInt;
```

Comment: this is not an int it is an int?

Answer (score 0):

The null conditional operator also unwraps the nullable variable. So after the "?." operator, the “Value” property is no longer needed.

I wrote a post that goes more into detail on how I came across this. In case you're wondering

http://www.ninjacrab.com/2016/09/11/c-how-the-null-conditional-operator-works-with-nullable-types/