# C# 6 Null Conditional Check

Tags: c#, c#-6.0, null-propagation-operator

How do I convert this into C# 6 Null Conditional Check?

```
var durationhours = product.ProductAudioAsset.TotalLengthInSeconds != null
    ? (short?)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(product.ProductAudioAsset.TotalLengthInSeconds.Value).TotalHours
    : null;
```

where TotalLengthInSeconds is nullable short

Comment: I would use an extra temporary variable for clarity. Why do you think a null conditional is the way to go?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31811392/null-conditional-operator-not-working-with-nullable-types

Comment: Why are you working with `short`? Stay with `double` - it's more precise and faster.

Comment: @ClickRick , Are you suggesting that I shouldn't consider using C# 6 null conditional check for this case?

Comment: @Enigmativity, legacy issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create an extension method to help:

```
public static short SecondsAsTotalHours(this short value)
{
    return (short)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(value).TotalHours;
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
var durationhours = product.ProductAudioAsset.TotalLengthInSeconds?.SecondsAsTotalHours();
```

Comment: This is a good answer. I would rename TimeSpanFromSeconds to SecondsAsTotalHours or something similar though.